# Chrome app in web store works fine for me, but nobody else. Possible key error?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I created a chrome app which uses the identity api, and it is deployed on the chrome web store. I cleared the dev version from my computer and downloaded it myself and it works wonderfully.

All it really does is get your identity, use that to grab a token that can be used to access the json representation of a google doc.

My teammate downloaded the app from the store and it and it isn't working at all. It seems that the app is not able to get a token, and therefore doesn't grab the json from the restricted google doc. I tried re-uploading the app with the `key.pem` in the root directory of the zip file, but with no luck.

What possible reason could there be for this? The only thing that I could think of is that my computer has a particular key on it. Any ideas.

Much appreciated.

Comment: What if you use another computer to install the item with your account?

Comment: Could you provide the AppID of your item?

Comment: @gui47 That was instructive, thanks. I just tried on my other computer and lo and behold, chrome.identity did not work. Do you think there might be something in my mac's keychain that isn't getting to end users? I'm afraid the id is irrelevant since its published privately for my organization.

Comment: I think the key needs to be there for the API to work and you have to copy key to your manifest. See reference to get details: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I had previously cached my auth token from when I was developing locally.

Since your offline development version of the chrome app must have the same 64-character ID as the one that you upload (if you want api credentials to work for you), you have to be mindful of cached Oauth tokens. You can easily find them at `chrome://identity-internals` where you can revoke the tokens to simulate a user opening the app for the first time.

In my case, I initially had

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
        "interactive": true
    }, function(token) {
```

inside `window.onload`. I later changed it to false, which didn't matter since I already had one cached for who knows how long. Thus, the app failed to authenticate for anyone else. Google recommends including a button or any other UI element for initiating the `chrome.getAuthToken` method because bandwidth issues often lead to a messy situation. I refactored this code to use `interactive: true` only if an auth token is not already present.